# Showing "open" or "closed" based on the current time

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, css, dom

I'm using this code to have a site show either "Open" or "Closed" depending on what the current time  is.

I'm a junior developer and I want to show this to my boss but one of the Senior Developers said to make it more robust/reusable before I do.

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
var currentDay = currentDate.getDay();
var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
var currentMinute = currentDate.getMinutes();

function openClose() {
  if(currentDay >= 1 && currentDay <= 4) { 
    document.getElementById("friday").style.display = "none";
    if (currentHour >= 8 && currentHour <= 21) { 
      document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "none";
    }
  else {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
  }
}
if (currentDay === 5) { 
  document.getElementById("mon-thurs").style.display = "none";
  if (currentHour >= 8 && currentHour <= 17.5) { 
    document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
  }
}
if (currentDay === 0 || currentDay === 6) { 
  document.getElementById("open").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("friday").style.display = "none";
}
};

setInterval(openClose(), 5000);
```

```css
.layout-header .header-one #open,
.layout-header .header-one #closed,
.layout-header .header-one #friday,
.layout-header .header-one #mon-thurs {
   display: inline-block;
   color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="open-display">
 <div id="open">Open</div>
 <div id="closed">Closed</div>
 <div id="mon-thurs">Sales: 8am - 8pm</div>
 <div id="friday">Sales: 8am - 5:30pm</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about if the working hours is in two shift everyday without day off. ie.
12:30pm to 3:30pm & 6:00pm to 12:30am. i tried but only noon shift is showing correct but evening is giving closed

Answer (score 7):

The first bug is that you are misusing `setInterval()`.  You should be **passing a function**, not the void result of the function, when calling `setInterval()`.

Even if you had used `setInterval()` correctly, you still have a second bug, which is that **`currentDate` is set just once when the code loads**.  If you call `openClose()` every five seconds, you would get the same result every time!

Third, the JavaScript sets `.style.display = 'none'`, but **never resets elements to be visible**.  Therefore, even if the first two issues were corrected, your page would appear emptier and emptier through the course of the week.

The code should **degrade gracefully** in the absence of JavaScript.

Display decisions should be written in CSS.  Ideally, the JavaScript should refrain from making decisions like `.style.display = 'none'`, and should restrict itself to doing the minimum necessary (i.e. setting classes) to let the CSS work.

There is a giant maintenance headache: **the hours are encoded both in the HTML and the JavaScript**.  It is likely that someone in the future would edit one but forget to edit the other accordingly.  Furthermore, the JavaScript representation is both cryptic (what does `17.5` mean?) and cumbersome (all those `if` conditions!).  I recommend changing the JavaScript code so that it interprets the opening hours from the HTML.  The easiest way would be to store the hours redundantly as machine-readable attributes in the HTML.

```js
function isOpen(timeRangeEl, date) {
    var day = '' + date.getDay();
    var hhmm = ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

    var days = timeRangeEl.getAttribute('data-days');
    var openTime = timeRangeEl.getAttribute('data-open');
    var closeTime = timeRangeEl.getAttribute('data-close');
    return days.indexOf(day) >= 0 && openTime <= hhmm && hhmm < closeTime;
}

function openClose() {
    var date = new Date();
    var display = document.getElementById('open-display');
    var els = display.getElementsByClassName('timerange');
    var anyActive = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        if (isOpen(els[i], date)) {
            anyActive = true;
            els[i].className = els[i].className.replace(/ *inactive\b/g, '');
        } else if (els[i].className.indexOf('inactive') < 0) {
            els[i].className += ' inactive';
        }
    }
    if (anyActive) {
        display.className = 'open';
    } else {
        display.className = 'closed';
    }
}

setInterval(openClose, 5000);
openClose();
```

```css
#open-display.open > .timerange.inactive,
#open-display.open .days {
     display: none;
}
#open-display.open > .openclosed::before {
    content: 'Open';
}
#open-display.closed > .openclosed::before {
    content: 'Closed';
}
```

```html
<div id="open-display">
 <div class="openclosed"></div>
 <div class="timerange" data-days="1,2,3,4" data-open="08:00" data-close="20:00">Sales: <span class="days">Mon - Thu</span> 8am - 8pm</div>
 <div class="timerange" data-days="5" data-open="08:00" data-close="17:30">Sales: <span class="days">Fri</span> 8am - 5:30pm</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think we should call the function once before setting the interval because I can see text changes after some time.

Comment: And yes you are right, I think presentation should go to CSS, data to HTML and logic to JS.

Answer (score 3):

I concur with the great points that [200_success♦](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) made. The suggestions below might not make the code much more re-usable, but should make it more robust.

#### DOM-queries.

Be aware that every query of the DOM is expensive! It is best to cache lookups for elements. For more information about this, I suggest reading [Stop writing Slow Javascript](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/) - especially the section labeled **Cache DOM Lookups**.

Using that information, it is good to declare the variables for the DOM lookups outside the functions so they can be re-used. Additionally, the code should wait until the DOM is ready, lest the queries to get elements fail due to an external dependency that requires a long time to load. For this, use [document.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and pass the *type* argument [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), followed by the code to be run.

In your original code, the functions like `openClose()` query the DOM each time for elements - e.g.:

```
function openClose() {
    if(currentDay >= 1 && currentDay <= 4) { 
        document.getElementById("friday").style.display = "none";
```

so move those to a function called when the DOM is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    //these could be declared with const instead of var, unless older browsers need to be supported
    var friday= document.getElementById('friday');
    var monThurs = document.getElementById("mon-thurs");
    var open = document.getElementById("open");
    var closed = document.getElementById("closed");


  function isOpen(timeRangeEl, date) {
    if(currentDay >= 1 && currentDay <= 4) { 
      friday.style.display = "none";
```

#### Use CSS

If you read that article mentioned earlier, the section **Don’t touch my DOM, bro** discusses how modifying the `style` property can cause performance losses.

Instead, add and remove classes. This can be done directly using the [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property, or using the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) interface.

Instead of modifying the *style* attribute, a class *hidden* could be added:

```
friday.classList.add('hidden');
```

where there is a CSS rule:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

#### Updated code

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
var currentDay = currentDate.getDay();
var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
var currentMinute = currentDate.getMinutes();
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var friday = document.getElementById('friday');
  var monThurs = document.getElementById("mon-thurs");
  var open = document.getElementById("open");
  var closed = document.getElementById("closed");

  function openClose() {
    //reset display each time this function runs
    [monThurs, friday, open, closed].forEach(function(element) {
      element.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
    if (currentDay >= 1 && currentDay <= 4) {
      friday.classList.add('hidden');
      if (currentHour >= 8 && currentHour <= 21) {
        closed.classList.add('hidden');
      } else {
        open.classList.add('hidden');
      }
    }
    if (currentDay === 5) {
      monThurs.classList.add('hidden');
      if (currentHour >= 8 && currentHour <= 17.5) {
        closed.classList.add('hidden');
      } else {
        open.classList.add('hidden');
      }
    }
    if (currentDay === 0 || currentDay === 6) {
      open.classList.add('hidden');
      friday.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  };

  setInterval(openClose, 5000);
  openClose();
});
```

```css
.layout-header .header-one #open,
.layout-header .header-one #closed,
.layout-header .header-one #friday,
.layout-header .header-one #mon-thurs {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="open-display">
  <div id="open">Open</div>
  <div id="closed">Closed</div>
  <div id="mon-thurs">Sales: 8am - 8pm</div>
  <div id="friday">Sales: 8am - 5:30pm</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Great answers from [200_success♦](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) and [Sam Onela](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120114/sam-onela).

Maybe I can throw in my two cents here as well and this is more like a suggestion rather than a full featured example. Let's take a look at this:

```
setInterval(openClose, 5000);
```

You run the check **every 5 seconds** over and over again.

This shouldn't be necessary because you actually know when you have to run the script again: *the moment the state `open|closed` changes.*

If you store the state somewhere and calculate the difference between now and then you only need to tun your script once using `setTimeout`:

Example HTML:

```
<div data-target data-open="8:00" data-close="18:0"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]')[0];
var state = 'open';

function changeState() {
  state = 'open' === state ? 'closed' : 'open';
  alert(state);
}

function runNext() {
  var now = new Date();
  var upcoming;
  var nextChange;
  var deltaDay = 0;
  var deltaMS;

  if ('open' === state) {
    nextChange = element.getAttribute('data-close').split(':');
  } else {
    nextChange = element.getAttribute('data-open').split(':');
    if (24 > now.getHours()) {
      deltaDay = 1;
    }
  }

  upcoming = new Date(
    now.getFullYear(),
    now.getMonth(),
    now.getDate() + deltaDay,
    nextChange[0],
    nextChange[1],
    0,
    0
  );

  deltaMS =  upcoming - now;

  setTimeout(function() {
    changeState();
  }, deltaMS); 
}

runNext();
```

You can test it in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ff95nre9/) by modifying the `data-close`-attribute.

---

**Important note:** In this example the store would open and close every day at the same time. Of course this must be extended with the actual working days and their respective opening hours - coming from a configuration object for example. Also `state` must be set initially and could be a `boolean` too – used a string to make the example easier to follow.